# Returning Data from REST service using Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm somewhat new to Angular, and I'm trying to get data from a REST service (consumed by an Angular service) in my controller. I have a way that works, but my main question is why my first attempt doesn't. What I have in my service is something like

```
getNames: function () {

    var request = $http.get('http://uri.of/rest/names');

    return (request.then(
        function (response) {
            return response.data;
        },function(response){ 
            return 'error'}
        )
    );
}
```

and I want to grab this in my controller with a line like

```
$scope.names = $restService.getNames();
```

but instead I have to use what feels like a roundabout solution

```
$restService.getNames().then(
    function(returnData){
        $scope.names = returnData;
    }
);
```

Is there a more streamlined way of accomplishing this? I think my problem stems from not having a complete understanding of how promises work here, but it seems like there should be a simpler way of assigning the data returned by this function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could think of using angular-resource `$resource` instead of `$http` API

Comment: There's nothing invalid about your approach. That is how you evaluate the result of a promise.

Comment: *"Is there a more streamlined way of accomplishing this"* ... No. Note that while it may seem like extra work the benefits are that you can catch errors anywhere in the chain

Comment: Okay, I guess that does make sense. Thank you!